# Computing S-value from R-squared for SVM?

Tags: python, statistics, standard-deviation

I split a dataset consisting of 3 columns for `X` and 1 column for `y`.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)
```

I then a support vector regression model to generate predictions

```
clf = svm.SVR(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

I then computed the R-squared value

```
r2_score(y_pred, y_test)
```

How do I then compute the S-value? Is it just `stdev(y_pred)*sqrt(1-R^2)`